# Elasticsearch.NET NEST Object Initializer syntax for a highlight request

Tags: c#, nest, object-initializers, elasticsearch-net

I've got:

```
        var result = _client.Search<ElasticFilm>(new SearchRequest("blaindex", "blatype")
        {
            From = 0,
            Size = 100,
            Query = titleQuery || pdfQuery,
            Source = new SourceFilter
            {
                Include = new []
                {
                    Property.Path<ElasticFilm>(p => p.Url),
                    Property.Path<ElasticFilm>(p => p.Title),
                    Property.Path<ElasticFilm>(p => p.Language),
                    Property.Path<ElasticFilm>(p => p.Details),
                    Property.Path<ElasticFilm>(p => p.Id)
                }
            },
            Timeout = "20000"
        });
```

And I'm trying to add a highlighter filter but I'm not that familiar with the Object Initializer (OIS) C# syntax. I've checked [NEST official pages](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/highlighting.html) and SO but can't seem to return any results for specifically the (OIS).

I can see the Highlight property in the Nest.SearchRequest class but I'm not experienced enough (I guess) to simply construct what I need from there - some examples and explanations as to how to employ a highlighter **with OIS** would be hot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the fluent syntax:

```
var response= client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Name).Query("test")))
    .Highlight(h => h.OnFields(fields => fields.OnField(f => f.Name).PreTags("<tag>").PostTags("</tag>"))));
```

and this is by object initialization:

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    Query = new QueryContainer(new MatchQuery{Field = Property.Path<Document>(p => p.Name), Query = "test"}),
    Highlight = new HighlightRequest
    {
        Fields = new FluentDictionary<PropertyPathMarker, IHighlightField>
        {
            {
                Property.Path<Document>(p => p.Name),
                new HighlightField {PreTags = new List<string> {"<tag>"}, PostTags = new List<string> {"</tag>"}}
            }
        }
    }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(searchRequest);
```

**UPDATE**

NEST 7.x syntax:

```
var searchQuery = new SearchRequest
{
    Highlight = new Highlight
    {
        Fields = new FluentDictionary<Field, IHighlightField>()
            .Add(Nest.Infer.Field<Document>(d => d.Name),
                new HighlightField {PreTags = new[] {"<tag>"}, PostTags = new[] {"<tag>"}})
    }
};
```

My document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: The `PropertyPathMarker` class has been dropped from the NEST library since version 6.  Any idea how this would be done for newer versions?

Comment: Much appreciated.  I find the official documentation lacking and am looking for more extensive documentation / learning resources wrt the entire NEST API.  Any alternate documentation / learning resources you can suggest?

Comment: I think official [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) are getting better and better every time. If you can't find any help there I think a good idea is to create an issue in [the repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) so guys know what community is struggling with :)