# how to pass an array of methods in C#

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In NEST, Elasticsearch library for .NET. For highlighting on query.

In `Highlight` method of NEST, How we can pass an array of actions as parameter to `onFields(Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<T>>[] fielddata)` method?

thanks.

Comment: Maybe this one will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436373/elasticsearch-net-nest-object-initializer-syntax-for-a-highlight-request/30436812#30436812

Comment: i'd change the title...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below:

```
var highlighters = new Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<YourObject>>[3];
highlighters[0] = h => h.OnField("field1");
highlighters[1] = h => h.OnField("field2");
highlighters[2] = h => h.OnField("field3");

searchDescriptor.Highlight(h => h.OnFields(highlighters));
```